# Developing a Rails app in a language other than english

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm building a new rails app and it's end users will all be spanish speakers. I figured I should use rails' I18n API but it feels like this is meant for translating an app that's already written in english. What I mean by that is that internally rails looks things up (models, table names, routes) with the english locale. Thus it feels weird to name your models in spanish if they are not going to be pluralized correctly when creating the schema.

Anyone has best practices for this kind of situation? Should I just name everything in english and then map the translations on the es.yml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the application should be viewed by spanish end users, you are probably better off coding it in english. This means writing english ruby code, english routes, english models etc. The only thing that should be spanish is the text on your web sites.

Some reasons:

- All reserved words in ruby are english.
- Libraries/Framework use english naming.
- Pluralization etc. is in english.
- Better chance of getting help on StackOverflow if the code snippet is in english.
- You never know, maybe someday it will turn into a collaboration project with non spanish speaking developers.

As for the i18n api, you may skip using it for now if you only should present the site content in one language.

Answer (score 2):

Write your code (and translation keys) in whatever language you prefer and use your `es.yml` for the translated language.

Here's an example of how you'd use I18n throughout your app:

**app/controllers/things_controller.rb**

```
def create
  thing = Thing.new(params[:id])
  if thing.save
    redirect_to thing, notice: t('cosa.crear.prosperidad')
  else
    flash.now.alert = t('cosa.crear.fracaso')
  end
end
```

**app/views/things/index.html.erb**

```
<h1><%= t('cosa.texto_de_ayuda') %></h1>
```

**config/locales/es.yml**

```
es:
  cosa:
    texto_de_ayuda: "Necesita ayuda para la creación de las cosas?"
    crear:
      prosperidad: "Cosa fue creado con éxito"
      fracaso: "Hubo un problema al crear su cosa"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no golden rule, but I think code should be written in English (even if you start writing in Spanish you may mix Spanish and English words and make a mess in your code).

About the i18n, you should use it not only for translating your app from a language to another, but also to specify textual elements that will be shown to the user. Hence you can have all that content organized into an unique file. It's better for maintenance and code organization and you can specify the default language (.yml file) that Rails should use.